# Integration Test Azure Functions with ServiceBus

Tags: azure-functions, integration-testing, azureservicebus

I made a `Testhost` class to inherit the DI of my `Startup` class in the Azure Functions app. It allows me to run the integration tests without too much hassle.

It looks like this:

```cs
public class TestHost
{
    public TestHost()
    {
        var startup = new TestStartup();
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebJobs(startup.Configure)
            .ConfigureServices(ReplaceTestOverrides)
            .Build();

        ServiceProvider = host.Services;
    }

    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }

    private void ReplaceTestOverrides(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(ICosmosDbService<GroupStorage>),
            new CosmosDbServiceStub<GroupStorage>()));
    }

    private class TestStartup : Viloc.ClientApi.Startup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            SetExecutionContextOptions(builder);
            base.Configure(builder);
        }

        private static void SetExecutionContextOptions(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure<ExecutionContextOptions>(o => o.AppDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        }
    }
}
```

In my integration test class, i then inject the function itself, to be called when running the actual test like this.

The GET calls that do not talk to my mediator, get handled just fine, but when i need to touch the servicebus. That where is went wrong.

I minified the `TestClass` to only include the POST call that uses the servicebus.

```cs
 [Collection(TestCollection.Name)]
public class RestTest: BaseIntegrationTest
{
    //Functions
    private readonly TestFunction _testFunction;
    
    //Repositories
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    
    //Internal dependencies
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public RestTest(TestHost testHost, DatabaseCleaner databaseCleaner): base(databaseCleaner)
    {
        _repository = testHost.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRepository>();
        _mapper = testHost.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();
        _httpContext = BaseIntegrationTest._httpContext;
        
        _testFunction = new TestFunction(new RequestValidation(), _mapper);
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public async Task POST_TestCall_ShouldReturnTrue()
    {
        var body = new class
        {
            testData = new List<Data>()
            {
                new Data()
                {
                    name = "test",
                    value = "test"
                }
            };
        };
        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body)));
        _httpContext.Request.Body = stream;
        
        var result = await _testFunction.RunAsync(_httpContext.Request, _collector);
        
        result.Should().Be(true);
    }
}
```

This is an example of a simple Azure Function, again minified to remove unnecessary code.

```cs
public class TestFunction
{
    private readonly RequestValidation _validation;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public TestFunction(RequestValidation validation, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _validation = validation;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    
    [FunctionName("TestFunction")]  
    [OpenApiOperation("test-call", "test", Description = "minfied function for stack")]
    [FunctionAuthorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "test")]
        HttpRequest req,
        [ServiceBus("test", Connection = "SERVICEBUS", EntityType = EntityType.Topic)]
        ICollector<Message> outputQueueItem)
    {
        return await HttpExtensions.HandleRequest<Testclass>(req, _validation, data =>
        {
            var request = new CreateTestCommand(_mapper.Map<TestClass>(data), Guid.Parse(req.GetClientId()));
            outputQueueItem.Add(MessageUtils.CreateMessage(request));
            return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(new AcceptedResult());
        });   
    }
}
```

The thing is need to pass a instance of `ICollector<Message>` which i pass now as `null`. How do i create an workable way of injecting a service bus, or passing the `ICollector<Message>`?